# how to ignore the incorrect samples and replace it by new samples in R?

Tags: r, graph

I have this code in r:

```
X=10;d=c()

for(x in 1:X){

 ga=erdos.renyi.game(100,0.04,directed = FALSE,loops = FALSE)

 if(!(is.connected(ga))){next} 

 d[x]=diameter(ga)

}
```

the aim of the code is to generate 10 random connected graphs from Erdos model then calculate the diameter of each graph. Now, Erdos model (sometimes) produces disconnected graphs for small probability p `(e.g. p=0.04)`. I tried by if condition to ignore the disconnected graphs but I need to replace the disconnected graphs with newly generated connected graphs. What I mean is that I want the code to reproduce more graphs until reach 10 random connected graphs.

one output of this code is

```
 d

 [1] NA  8  7 NA NA NA  7  7 NA  8
```

the NA because of the disconnected graphs.

Comment: Do you need the answer in some more languages?

Comment: Removed excess tags for being unrelated to question.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your `for` loop to a `while` loop should do the job.

```
library(igraph)
X=10
d=c()

x = 0
while(x<X) {
    ga=erdos.renyi.game(100,0.04,directed = FALSE,loops = FALSE)
    if(!(is.connected(ga))){ next} 
    x = x+1
    d[x]=diameter(ga)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need. @G5W